# iPhone 6 can’t find GPS

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

Recently my iPhone 6 GPS stopped working. I have searched for a solution but could not find anything useful. The only solution that was proposed from iFixit was to replace antenna. But what can happen with an antenna?
Sometimes hitting the phone against my knee helped to restore the signal again.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

I ordered a new battery from well known China site with the required tools to disassemble the phone.

When I've opened the phone I saw that some adhesive/isolator on the antenna was tired out from it's place. I've gently pushed it back. See attached image. That fixed my GPS issue.

[image: Make sure your antenna isolator is fine]

Topic was started here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/32727069
But apple forum policies do not allow you to post a fix that involves phone disassembly.

Wish that this post will help someone with the GPS problem.